# Hash display corresponding key and values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a hash that looks like this:

```
{"Title"=>"Harry Potter", "Author"=>"Jk rowling", "Date Published"=>"1997"}
```

Here's the html table when everything is working correctly:

[image]

Right now, I'm just iterating over the keys for the th and over the values for the td.

So here's my code:

```
%table
  %tr
    - data.each do |key, array|
        %th= key

  %tr
    - data.each do |key, array|
        %td= array
```

This works, but my problem is:

- If a value is blank, instead of leaving the column underneath the corresponding key blank, the next value is put there. So if the value for Author is left blank, then 1997 will shift to be underneath Author in the table.

Thanks for all help!

Comment: Are you using a particular gem for your view code? It's not standard Rails view format.

Comment: We need to see a more comprehensive example of your data. Show us some rows with missing values.

Comment: @mrbratch, its haml instead of erb. Is that what you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be `nil` and not generating the `th` or `td`. You could try this (note, I'm not totally familiar with the view gem you're using, so I'm taking a stab at it):

```
%table
  %tr
    - data.each do |key, array|
        %th= key || "&nbsp;".html_safe

  %tr
    - data.each do |key, array|
        %td= array || "&nbsp;".html_safe
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd do it more like this:

```
%table
  %tr
    - data.keys do |key|
        %th= key || '&nbsp;'

  %tr
    - data.values do |val|
        %td= val || '&lt;missing&gt;'
```

Using `keys` and `values` returns the keys and their respective values in the same order, so your headings and data will match up. If a key is missing the `&nbsp;` will help the column appear. If a value is missing `&lt;missing&gt;` should cause `<missing>` to display.

Without sample data and a working example in your code it's hard to show more without spending a lot of time cobbling together fake data, a view, etc.